# Using .range property on string that includes sheet name

Tags: vba, excel

I have a string inside a cell in a workbook that I am using to define the address of a range that a lookup should be done upon.

As an example, let's say the string is called LookupRange and has the value:

```
''Rate Sheet'!Y111:AA126
```

My problem is that in my code, when I set the range I have to use:

```
Set yRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Rate Sheet").Range(LookupRange)
```

Is there a way to use the .Range() property without using the .Worksheets() property?

For instance, maybe a way to do something like:

```
Set yRange = ThisWorkbook.Range(LookupRange)
```

If not, I guess I might have to write some code to extract the sheetname from the sheet range?

Comment: The Range is a property of a Worksheet.  The Worksheet should be referenced.

Comment: I realise this isn't an answer to your specific question exactly, but why are you putting lookup ranges inside a cell?  Have you considered creating named ranges, or even dynamic named ranges if your lookups change quite often.  Then you can reference them in vba using `application.names(MyNamedRange).RefersToRange.Value`

Comment: Because I want a non-VBA excel user to be able to change the ranges as needed.  And because I am taking over something that was originally done with formulas.

Comment: I am just surprised there isn't a VBA function to take a string that contains a sheet name and the address of a range and to convert that into a specific worksheet object and cell range that VBA can then work with.  I mean Excel is doing it on its all the time right?

Comment: @CharBram you've seen my answer, right?...Where exactly that happens. Check it is referencing the *correct* range by doing `debug.print rr.parent.name` to  check that it is referencing the sheet you expect/set, whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `LookupRange` is a String, you can extract the Sheet and Range from the string using `Mid()` and `InStr()`:

```
Sub TestIt()
Dim LookupRange As String

LookupRange = "'Rate Sheet'!Y111:AA126"

SheetL = Mid(LookupRange, 2, InStr(2, LookupRange, "'") - 2)
RangeL = Mid(LookupRange, InStr(1, LookupRange, "!") + 1, Len(LookupRange))

Set yRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetL).Range(RangeL)

End Sub
```

Comment: This is probably, the best answer for right now, simply extracting the sheet name and the range address using string functions.  I think in the end, I will simply re-design how they are storing the sheet name and address in cells or simply do this.  Still, I am surprised there is not a built in method or property that does this automatically!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what sort of look up you are doing, but this should work..(parse it as a string)

```
Sub range_set()

Dim rr As Range
Set rr = Range(CStr(Range("LookupRange")))

Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(1, rr, 2, False)

End Sub
```

Where the named range `"LookupRange"` is a single cell that contains the sheet address `"Sheet2!Y111:AA126"` (or whatever) to be used in a "lookup".

Comment: Yeah, every time I try this, when trying to set rr I get a run-time error.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set yRange = Application.Range("'Rate Sheet'!Y111:AA126")
```

Comment: Doesn't work.  It seems the range method of application is not accepting a sheet name within the string.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it works. Where do you get an error?

Comment: I will try an example again later today and report back. Maybe I was doing something wrong!